# shutdown - h *time* doesnt work with the laptop lid closed?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

I use shutdown -h time command to shutdown my laptop after a particular time. I observed that the laptop doesnt come to a halt after the set time if the lid of my laptop is closed. When i open the lid the next morning it tells " goint to halt". So how do i make ubuntu shotdown at a pre-set time even if the lid is closed.?

Comment: Umm, just a hunch, did you try changing the power options?

Comment: yea, but it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Go to power management settings and modified as settings as "Do Nothing" when laptop lid closed.

Then it will works

[image]

Comment: i had tried it before, it doesnt work

Comment: No bro , I am very sure. It will work If you set it Do Nothing on both cases like Battery and AC Plugged in

Comment: i have done it. really

Answer (score 0):

To make Ubuntu do nothing when sytem is closed

1.Open the  `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file in a text editor as root, for example,

```
 sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

3.Add a line `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` (make sure it's not commented out!),

Restart the systemd daemon with this command:

```
sudo restart systemd-logind
```